# Flex Change image color dynamically?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image

I have a image declared like the following:

```
[Bindable]
[Embed( source="assets/banana.png" )] 
public var iconBANANA : Class;
```

It is involving into `itemRenderer`, but I wish to change the color of the image when some event occurs (like clicking above or something).

The rest of the objects used the image shall remain unchanged, only the object on which the event has occurred shall change the color of the image.

But the biggest question is :

- How to change the image color mainly - like there is a Blue area on image - to turn it on Green, or Yellow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for are [Filters](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f-73a4773012528309923-8000.html#WSda78ed3a750d6b8f5ef2bd7012256e4b931-8000).  What you're explaning (changing one color to another) is not exactly trivial and going into some fairly complex image manipulation but you can get some results using the ColorMatrixFilter.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev Hey, could you share what you did specifically to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [beginBitmapFill](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html).

Comment: -1.  I think he's asking for Image manipulation here, not drawing API.

Comment: The drawing API is what you use for image manip. But I didn't claim it was a complete answer, it was a suggestion for direction -- one that I needed for a similar problem a couple of years ago.